# filter one data.frame by another data.frame by specific columns

Tags: r, dataframe

```
full = data.frame(group = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), values = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4))
filter = data.frame(group = c('a', 'b', 'c'), values = c(4, 3, 3))
## find rows of full where values are larger than filter for the given group
full[full$group == filter$group & full$values > filter$values, ]
```

prints an empty data.frame with the warning:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In full$group == filter$group :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>   2: In full$values > filter$values :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I'm looking for all the rows in `full` that match that criteria, to end up with: 
full

```
> group
group  values
    a      5
    c      4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
full[unlist(sapply(1:NROW(filter), function(i)
    which(full$group == filter$group[i] & full$values > filter$values[i]))),]
#  group values
#5     a      5
#7     c      4
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `merge`

```
full=merge(full,filter,by='group')
full=full[full$values.x>full$values.y,]
full$values.y=NULL
names(full)=c('group','values')
> full
  group values
5     a      5
7     c      4
```

Or `match`

```
full$Filter=filter$values[match(full$group,filter$group)]
full=full[full$values>full$Filter,]
full$Filter=NULL
> full
  group values
5     a      5
7     c      4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R functions `Map`, `split`, `unlist`, and logical indexing you can do

```
full[unlist(Map(">", split(full$values, full$group), split(filter$values, filter$group))),]
  group values
5     a      5
7     c      4
```

here, you split the value vectors by group into lists and feed these to `Map`, which applies `>`. As `Map` returns a list, `unlist` returns a logical vector which is fed to `[` for subsetting. Note that this requires that both data.frames are sorted by group and that each has the same levels in the group variable.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dt <- full %>%
  left_join(filter, by = "group") %>%
  dplyr::filter(values.x > values.y) %>%
  select(group, values = values.x)
dt
  group values
1     a      5
2     c      4
```

Or `purrr`.

```
library(purrr)

dt <- full %>%
  split(.$group) %>%
  map2_df(filter %>% split(.$group), ~.x[.x$values > .y$values, ])
dt
  group values
1     a      5
2     c      4
```

Answer (score 0):

[`join_by`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html) was added in dplyr 1.1.0 for more advanced join specifications:

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(full, filter, by = join_by(group == group, values > values)) |>
  select(group, values = values.x)
```

Note the equality condition and inequality conditions both have the same variable names. They are distinguished by the order of the data frames. The LHS refers to the first data frame (`full` in this case) and the RHS to the second data frame (`filter` in this case).